# Oracle SQL how to group by first and then compare frequency

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table looks like

```
 table   operation     employee
            '<'               id1
            '<'               id1
            '<'               id2
            '*'               id3
            '/'               id1
```

For each operation, I want to know which employee does the most? Which employee does the 2nd?

Comment: *I want to know which employee does the most?* Does the most what?

Comment: I am sorry. I mean for a specific operation, which employee does the most. For example, for operation '<', employee id1 did 5 times, id2 did 3 times and id3 only did 1 time. So we need to figure out id1 did 1st most, id2 did 2nd most, and id3 did 3rd most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT operations.operation, employees.employee, employees.rank
FROM (
  SELECT t1.operation
  FROM table t1
  GROUP BY t1.operation
) operations INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t2.employee, t2.operation, COUNT(1) rank
  FROM table t2
  GROUP BY t2.employee
) employees ON operations.operation = employees.operation
ORDER BY operations.operation, employees.rank DESC
```

For every operation, we are getting the count of each corresponding employee. The operations are distinct due to the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in the subquery and the employees are distinct due to `GROUP BY` in the other subquery. We join the two subqueries on the operation and then sort by the number of times each employee is associated with an operation.

Comment: Oracle has a [RANK function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm)